# Prove that $\left<a\right>$ is a subgroup of $C(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any element a in any group $G$, prove that $\left<a\right>$ is a subgroup of $C(a)$ (the centralizer of $a$)

I think I know how to approach this problem, but I'm not quite sure how to put it in a formal proof. By definition, the centralizer is the set of elements that commute with $a$. So, $\left<a\right>$ has to be a subgroup of $C(a)$ since $\left<a\right>$ contains all the elements that commute with $a$. Right?

Comment: I agree that $\left<a\right>$ is a subset of $C(a)$ because every element of $\left<a\right>$ commutes with $a$. You might also need to show that it satisfies the group axioms, though I imagine that when you were introduced to the definition of $\left<a\right>$, you were also given the proof that it was a group, and if so, then you're done.

Comment: $<a>=\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, right? So $a.a^n=a^{n+1}=a^n.a$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the key facts:

- $a \in H \implies \left<a\right> \subseteq H$, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$
- $a \in C(a)$
- $C(a)$ is a subgroup of $G$